# bind an insertion to a mouse click

Tags: key-bindings, mouse, interactive

I need to change a space to a `|` here and there and i guessed that the best possibility were to bind a mouse click and the insertion of the pipe

```
(global-set-key [s-mouse-1] '(insert "|"))
```

But when I tested my idea I was told

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (insert "|")
```

I have read [49.3.10 Rebinding Mouse Buttons](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Buttons.html) but it did not mention which types of commands are *bindable* to mouse clicks.

Comment: Insert is a function but not a command. You need to write an interactive command for the mouse click to call.

Comment: @Dan Ah, I've tagged properly my question!  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

A function for which `commandp` returns `t` is an [`interactive` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html#What-Is-a-Function), i.e. one which calls `(interactive ...)` as the first thing in its body. So
you can write a function like this:

```
(defun insert-vertbar ()
   (interactive)
   (insert "|"))
```

and bind it to the mouse click:

```
(global-set-key [S-mouse-2] #'insert-vertbar)
```

`interactive` has a lot of wrinkles (which are not necessary in this case, but they can be valuable when you need to write a more complicated function): you can find out more by using your emacs's help facility: `C-h f interactive`, and/or looking it up in the
the [emacs lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html).

N.B. In my case, `[S-mouse-1]` was intercepted by the window manager before emacs could get to it, so I was not able to bind it to that. I had to use `[S-mouse-2]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of help [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44945/9672) and [there](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_mouse_wheel_config.html) I have put together what I need

```
(defun insert-vertbar (ev)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((p1 (posn-point (event-start ev))))
    (goto-char p1)
    (delete-char 1)
    (insert "|")))
(global-set-key [s-mouse-1] #'insert-vertbar)
```

I'm a bit doubtful that

```
  (let ((p1 (posn-point (event-start ev)))) ...
```

is the best — most clean way of changing the position of the cursor, if you'd like to comment you're welcome...